# WPF Xceed PropertyGrid ComboBox binding - how to populate with a list of items from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, propertygrid, xceed

I am using an `Xceed PropertyGrid` to show properties for various objects. In most cases this is straightforward. I just set the `SelectedObject` property the appropriate object.

However, I have a case where one object property is a reference to another object from a collection of a different class. I have created a simplified example here for demonstration and testing purposes. In this example, the `Person` object has a `City` property, which is an instance of the `CityModel` class. So for any given `Person`, the user should be able to select their city of residence from the `cities` collection. Collections of both people and cities are - or at least would be in the real thing - dynamic and user-changeable.

I can populate a `ComboBox` using an `EditorTemplate` but am having problems referencing the `cities` collection.

If trying to define the `Source` as a `StaticResource`, I am not getting the expected behavior. [This How-to from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-a-collection-and-display-information-based-on-selection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) shows an `ObservableCollection` (`People`) being defined as a `Resource` and subsequently referenced as a `StaticResource` in a data binding. When I try to do the same, Visual Studio is clearly expecting the `Resource` definition to be a class rather than a class instance. It gives me the option of `CityModel` or `PersonModel`, but not the `cities` collection which is what I thought I should be specifying here based on the How-to.

[image: Intellisense showing available options for data source definition]

If `Source` does not point to the collection, I'm not sure how and where to specify it in the binding since (again based on Intellisense) it cannot go in the `Path`.

Without using a `StaticResource` I can do either of the following, both of which result in a blank list:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=DataContext.cities, Path=Name}"

ItemsSource="{Binding Source=cities, Path=Name}"
```

Or this, which results in the text string "cities" being used as the source:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=cities}"
```

In the code below I can get the desired result by duplicating the `cities` collection within the `Person` class, which exposes it to the `ComboBox` without a having to specify a `Source`, but this is very much a workaround.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Padding="0,10,0,5">People:</TextBlock>
        <ListBox Name="listPeople" ItemsSource="{Binding people}" DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" />
        <TextBlock Padding="0,10,0,5">Cities:</TextBlock>
        <ListBox Name="listCities" ItemsSource="{Binding cities}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" />
        <TextBlock Padding="0,10,0,5">Properties:</TextBlock>
        <xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="MyPropertyGrid">
            <xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
                <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition TargetProperties="City">
                    <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Instance.citiesList}" SelectedValue="{Binding Instance.City}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
                </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition>
            </xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
        </xctk:PropertyGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    
    public ObservableCollection<CityModel> cities { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CityModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> people { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        // Create some cities...
        CityModel tokyo = new CityModel() { Id = 0, Name = "Tokyo" };
        CityModel london = new CityModel() { Id = 1, Name = "London" };
        CityModel buenosAires = new CityModel() { Id = 2, Name = "Buenos Aries" };
        cities = new ObservableCollection<CityModel>() { tokyo, london, buenosAires };

        // Create some people...
        PersonModel juan = new PersonModel() { FirstName = "Juan", LastName = "Garcia", City = buenosAires };
        PersonModel bridget = new PersonModel() { FirstName = "Bridget", LastName = "Jones", City = london };
        PersonModel aoife = new PersonModel() { FirstName = "Aoife", LastName = "O'Connor", City = tokyo };
        people = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>() { juan, bridget, aoife };

        // Workaround in order to expose list of cities along with Person properties...
        foreach (PersonModel person in people) { person.citiesList = cities; }

    }

    private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
        MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = listBox.SelectedItem;
    }
}

public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";

    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";

    public CityModel City { get; set; } = new CityModel();

    // Workaround in order to expose list of cities along with Person properties...
    public ObservableCollection<CityModel> citiesList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CityModel>();
}

public class CityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}
```

Comment: Did you google this? First hit i found was https://www.google.com/amp/s/pccoder.wordpress.com/2019/02/13/wpf-xceed-propertygrid-binding-dynamic-list-to-combobox/amp/

Comment: Yes. That is what I used as the basis for my testing.